# Casting json object to typed object with only a subset of properties

Tags: c#, json.net

I am selecting a json object as follows:

```
var gridRenderer = json.SelectToken("$..gridRenderer").FirstOrDefault();
```

The line above gives the following subset of the JSON shown at the end of the question:

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "gridVideoRenderer": { } // Many properties omitted.
    },
    // Other entries omitted.
```

Located at the path:

```
contents.twoColumnBrowseResultsRenderer.tabs[0].tabRenderer.content.sectionListRenderer.contents[0].itemSectionRenderer.contents[0].gridRenderer
```

As you can see above there is a lot of data. I want to cast this to typed object with a sub set of properties:

```
var ee = gridRenderer.Cast<GridRenderSection>();
```

First I just wanted to get an array with objects with the videoid. I have following classes:

```
[JsonObject("gridRenderSection")]
public class GridRenderSection
{
     [JsonProperty("items")]
     public List<GridVideoRenderer> Items{ get; set; }
}

public class GridVideoRenderer
{
    [JsonProperty("videoId")]
    public string VideoId { get; set; }
}
```

But I get following error:
"Unable to cast object of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray' to type 'GridRenderSection'."

Normally you can cast subset of types objects, is that not possible with the Cast function, or am I missing something here?

Sample code (notice you can see json on the link provided in sample code or below):

```
var jsonStr = string.Empty;
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    jsonStr = client.DownloadString("https://srv-file2.gofile.io/download/J1iBAd/json1.json");
}

var json = JObject.Parse(jsonStr);

var gridRenderer = json.SelectToken("$..gridRenderer").FirstOrDefault();
var ee = gridRenderer.Cast<GridRenderSection>();
```

JSON:

```
{  
  "contents": {
    "twoColumnBrowseResultsRenderer": {
      "tabs": [
        {
          "tabRenderer": {
            "title": "Videoer",
            "selected": true,
            "content": {
              "sectionListRenderer": {
                "contents": [
                  {
                    "itemSectionRenderer": {
                      "contents": [
                        {
                          "gridRenderer": {
                            "items": [
                              {
                                "gridVideoRenderer": {
                                  "videoId": "lzSlEtuHgAU"
                                }
                              },
                              {
                                "gridVideoRenderer": {
                                  "videoId": "F5Opl1llzWw"
                                }
                              }
                            ]
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                ]            
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few problems here:

1. Your query `json.SelectToken("$..gridRenderer")` is returning a single [`JToken`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken.htm) corresponding to the following JSON object:

   ```
   {
     "items": [
       {
         "gridVideoRenderer": {
           "videoId": "lzSlEtuHgAU"
         }
       },
       {
         "gridVideoRenderer": {
           "videoId": "F5Opl1llzWw"
         }
       }
     ]
   }
   ```

   You are trying to cast this to a `GridRenderSection`, but `JToken` has no explicit or implicit [type conversion](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Operators_T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken.htm) to arbitrary types -- only to simple `IConvertible` types.  Instead you will need to *deserialize* to `GridRenderSection` using [`ToObject<GridRenderSection>()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_ToObject__1.htm):

   ```
   var ee = gridRenderer.ToObject<GridRenderSection>();
   ```
2. You are calling `FirstOrDefault()` on the return from `SelectToken()`:

   ```
   json.SelectToken("$..gridRenderer").FirstOrDefault();
   ```

   However, [`SelectToken()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_SelectToken.htm) already returns a **single** `JToken` that matches the query, in this case a `JObject`.  (If there is more than one match, `SelectToken()` throws an exception.)  Later, when you do `.FirstOrDefault()` you are grabbing the first property of the object and trying to deserialize that single property into your data model, which is wrong.

   Generally, if you are calling `SelectToken()` there is no need to call `.FirstOrDefault()`; it's more commonly applied to **[`SelectTokens()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_SelectTokens.htm)** when there might be many matches and only the first is needed.
3. Your data model does not match your JSON.  `videoId` is nested inside a container object `gridVideoRenderer` which needs to be modeled like so:

   ```
   public class GridRenderSection
   {
        [JsonProperty("items")]
        public List<GridRenderSectionItem> Items{ get; set; }
   }

   public class GridRenderSectionItem
   {
       public GridVideoRenderer gridVideoRenderer { get; set; }
   }

   public class GridVideoRenderer
   {
       [JsonProperty("videoId")]
       public string VideoId { get; set; }
   }
   ```

Incidentally, if all you need are the `videoId` values, you could use the following `SelectTokens()` query to extract them directly:

```
var videoIds = json.SelectTokens("$..gridRenderer.items[*].gridVideoRenderer.videoId")
    .Select(t => t.ToString())
    .ToList();
```

Or if you want just a list of `GridVideoRenderer` objects:

```
var renderers = json.SelectTokens("$..gridRenderer.items[*].gridVideoRenderer")
    .Select(t => t.ToObject<GridVideoRenderer>())
    .ToList();
```

Demo fixed fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/oVnN3W).

Comment: Spot on. Thanks!

Comment: Just one comment. When using $..gridRenderer.items[*].gridVideoRenderer I get following:  {{ "videoId": "lzSlEtuHgAU" }}
{{ "videoId": "F5Opl1llzWw" }}. Notice there is two square bracket wich makes my cast failing. Is there anyway to avoid this?

Comment: The doubling of the curly braces -- `{{` and `}}` -- is some sort of visualization artifact added by the debugger.  What your query is returning is an object containing one property `"videoId"`.  If you want to select the property itself you need to add the additional `.videoId` to the query path as shown in my answer.

Comment: OK, makes sense. But if that is the case shouldn't  var ee = gridRendererVideos.Cast<GridVideoRenderer[]>(); cast work? Its a super basic array but gives following "Unable to cast object of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' to type 'GridVideoRenderer[]'."

Comment: [`Enumerable.Cast(IEnumerable)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.cast?view=netframework-4.8) casts every element in a sequence to the target type -- i.e. you're trying to iterate through the `JProperty` children of `gridRendererVideos` and cast each one to `GridVideoRenderer[]`.  But, as said before, you can't do that.  Firstly because there is no cast operator from `JToken` to arbitrary complex types, and secondly because you're trying to cast the `JProperty` itself to `GridVideoRenderer[]` rather than the value, which doesn't make sense.

Comment: Roger. Thanks. I will convert them manually for each property.

Comment: @ThomasSegato - answer updated.  You don't need to convert manually, you can deserialize with `ToObject()`.  You just cant **cast** to the type you want, `Enumerable.Cast<T>()` is not useful to you here.

Comment: Thanks alot. You have been very helpfull. Apreciated!